# drupal---hook_theme()

Tags: drupal, module

when i viewed the drupal sourcecode, i found there're lots of theme() function,eg:theme_table($variables),theme_table($variables),theme_username()..., from the drupal documentation i know when use a theme() function, there must be a registry to it. namely,hook_theme(). but i can't find the hook_theme of the theme_table,theme_username...why?

Answer (score 1):

The functions you mention above are registered via [drupal_common_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_common_theme/6), which is called from the the [system_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_theme/6) function.